# How can I send logs to papertrail heroku addon?

Tags: heroku

I contacted to customer support in papertrail and he or she told me to send logs to papertrail via logplex.

but I don't know how to do that though I check the document below.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex

How can I send logs to papertrail heroku addon?

I also checked this article and it said logplex is DEPRECATED.
https://github.com/heroku/logplex/blob/master/README.md

Is it correct way to send logs to papertrail via logplex?

thank you

Comment: Do you need to do _anything_? As long as you print your logs to `stdout` or `stderr`, they should get picked up by Heroku's default logger. And if you use the Papertrail addon, those logs should end up in Papertrail.

Comment: Thanks Chris
I want to email notification when cron process is over.
Is it possible to send email without addons like papertrail?

Comment: Papertrail and email have nothing to do with one another. Please don't ask new questions in comments. If you want to ask about sending email on Heroku, first search for existing questions. Then, if you can't find one, ask a new one.